# Excel Tricky date based formula required - Experts Please assist

Tags: excel

I need to add the total of sales done per month. That is add figures in column 2 if dates fall between 1st of every month till 31st.

This should be current. That is if May ends and June begins excel should automatically stop calculating figures of may and only tally the ones from june till june end and so on for all months and following years

Is this possible or too complicated

Please note I follow this date pattern: dd/mm/yy or dd.mm.yy

Comment: It's way too complicated. I advise you to give up. Or, try something and ask about that.

Answer (score 0):

Obviusly if you post what you have try to do ...
Starting Points !
Following the scheme:

[image]

Add the formula:

```
c2 -> =MONTH(A2)
f2 -> =SUMIFS($B$2:$B$7;$C$2:$C$7;ROW(F1))
```

and autocomplete...
You have the sum for month. If you add also the years...